# Using irrelevant fields

Tags: agda

Is it possible to declare fields in a record irrelevant but still use them somewhere?

Suppose I have

```
postulate f : ℕ → ℕ
record Silly x : Set where
  field
    n : ℕ
    s : f n ≡ x

open Silly
```

Then, I can

```
same-silly : ∀{x} {p q : Silly x} → f (n p) ≡ f(n q)
same-silly {x} {p} {q} = ≡-trans (s p) (≡-sym (s q))
```

But if I use dotted-fields,

```
record Silly x : Set where
  field
    n : ℕ
    .s : f n ≡ x  -- note the dot
```

then `same-silly` can no longer be proven ---not by me at least.
When I attempt to use `s`, as in the definition above, Agda informs me `Identifier s is declared irrelevant, so it cannot be used here`.

I understand that I declared `s` irrelevant by dotting it, but I still want a bit of access to it: enough access to define `same-silly`. Is there a way to have this little bit but not complete access? What I mean is that I am thinking of `s` as a coherency condition that I'd like to use once in a blue-moon, but not terrible important and so the dot. Maybe ignore this paragraph.

Is it possible to form `same-silly` and have `s` be dotted?

(

Aside: does the dotted pattern mean propositional equality coincides with the relation

```
_~_ : ∀{x} (p q : Silly x) → Set
p ~ q = n p ≡ n q
```

? In particular, by adding to the record `constructor _#_`, I can show

```
eq : ∀{m x}{p q : f m ≡ x} → (m # p) ≡ (m # q) 
eq = ≡-refl
```

but I'm not yet certain that dotting fields means that definitionally equality ignores the dotted fields.

I'm browsing http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/agda.php?n=ForkedReferenceManual.Records#Irrelevantfields; which says that there are projections for dotted fields, but it seems I cannot use them anywhere.

)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Apparently putting a dot before the function name allows me to access it! I'm thorougly confised, thouugh it's past 2 in the morning, maybe I should sleep. Anyhow, `  .s_ : ∀{x} (p : Silly x) → f (Silly.n p) ≡ x` and
  s p = Silly.s p` works (note no dot in the definition!). cf https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/1093

Comment: nope, it seems that `same-silly` still cannot be defined.  `.s` is an irrelevant name and ``Irrelevant names may only be used in irrelevant positions or in definitions of things which have been declared irrelevant.'' [http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.Irrelevance] Any help would be appreciated; thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

You can use irrelevant projections, but only when you are working in an irrelevant context. One way to enter an irrelevant context is to make the proof itself irrelevant:

```
.same-silly : ∀{x} {p q : Silly x} → f (n p) ≡ f(n q)
same-silly {x} {p} {q} = ≡-trans (s p) (≡-sym (s q))
```

This means that you will only be able to use the same-silly proof in irrelevant contexts as well.

Regarding your second question, the answer is yes: you can prove the following:

```
silly-equality : ∀ {n} {x y : Silly n} → x ~ y → x ≡ y
silly-equality refl = refl
```

So equality of the first projection (your *~* relation) really corresponds to propositional equality.