# Using irrelevant terms to prove irrelevant things

Tags: agda

In Agda 2.6.0.1, I would like to use an irrelevant proof term in a record, and then show that two of these records are equal based only on their data terms.

```
data Bools : Set where
  T : Bools
  F : Bools

record Thing : Set where
  field
    val : Bools
    .pr : val == T

.eq : (a b : Thing) -> a == b
eq record { val = a ; pr = pr1 } record { val = b ; pr = pr2 } = ?
```

I feel like I should be able to prove this by appealing to the fact that each `Thing` knows that its `val` is equal to `T`. (If `pr1` and `pr2` were both relevant, I could match on them to show that `a = T = b`; but then I'd need Streicher's K to give me the equality of the `Thing.pr` terms.)

Since `Thing.pr` is irrelevant, I certainly need to be in an irrelevant context before I can hope to use it. I thought I'd achieved that by putting a `.` in front of the name of `eq` in its declaration; but when I try and use `pr1` in the hole, I still get the usual "Variable `pr1` is declared irrelevant, so it cannot be used here" message.

Can I do what I want here? Can I make `eq` be sufficiently irrelevant that I can use `pr1` and `pr2` in its definition? The answer at [Using irrelevant fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585992/using-irrelevant-fields) suggests that I can, but for the life of me I don't see why Agda isn't accepting what I've got.

Comment: You can use `postulate .irrAx : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} -> .A -> A` from the documentation, but I don't understand why this is required.

Comment: @JannisLimperg That's a very sad postulate anyway - it states that you can extract information out of something you explicitly said you couldn't get information out of, as long as you promise not to use that information. I'm a bit squeamish about the sound of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pattern-match on `a` and `b`. Agda will realise that the only
possible case is the `a = T` and `b = T` one and you will then be able to discharge
the goal with `refl`.

By the way, `eq` does not need to be declared irrelevant.

Comment: I think that answers my question only insofar as my example is simple enough that Agda recognises the constraint implied by `pr`. With not much more complexity, I can make it so that Agda can't get anything out of `pr` during case-splitting, and I start needing to actually manipulate proof terms. I can live with this being impossible - I can always make different data structures which have the information in a simple enough form for Agda to recognise it - but it feels weird to be so completely at the mercy of the case-splitter.

Comment: You are not: [you can always eliminate an irrelevant proof of the empty type](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Empty.Irrelevant.html). So if you can write a (relevant) proof that `P → ⊥` and if you have an irrelevant proof of `P` you can use it to get an irrelevant proof of `⊥` which will be enough to dismiss the impossible branch.